# How to serve static files 'conditionally' in Django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have an application which includes templates maintained in their separate repos. Here is the directory structure:

[image]

As you can see each template has its own set of static files. My question is how can I go about rendering each template with its appropriate static files?? I'm open to any viable solution that can work in production. I use apache2 and mod_wsgi for production and I'm also ready to use dj-static if necessary.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you make your life so difficult? One static folder will be way more easy - to be maintained and to find something.

Comment: speedyGonzales, its is not my doing. It is totally outside my control. I have to work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a filter that you call on all static file paths, and pass the template static file path to your context.

First make an appropriate filter:

```
from django.template import Library
from urlparse import urljoin
register = Library()
from django.conf import settings


@register.filter
def make_static(relative_url, template_dir):
    base = urljoin(settings.STATIC_URL, template_dir)
    return urljoin(base, relative_url)
```

Now when rendering your template add a reference to where the template static files are based from:

```
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

template = get_template('template1/index.html')
context = Context({'template_dir': 'template1/'})
template.render(context)
```

In your actual templates use the filter like so:

```
<img src="{{'imgs/some_image.jpg'|make_static:template_dir}}">
```

This will really only be useful if each of your templates inherit from some base template that uses these generic paths, but each template needs a different image or something to look the way you'd like.

Comment: Thank you knbk. I understood your approach and it seems to be the right way. However, I'm getting an error "make_static requires 1 arguments, 0 provided" and i'm calling the filter as follows "<img src="{{'images/caessar.jpg'|make_static :template_dir}}">". What could be wrong??

Comment: Hey, I put in some extra spaces for the filter that was breaking the filter parsing. It's fixed now.

Comment: It works now but is still referring to /static/images/some_image.jpg, instead of the image in /static/templates2/images/some_image.jpg. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. urljoin works slightly different than I thought. In the context you should put {'template_dir': 'templates2/'} (Notice the extra slash). I've updated the answer.

Comment: You'll have to configure your STATICFILE_DIRS (you probably want to add your app/templates/ folder to it) and STATIC_ROOT in your settings.py, and for production you'll need to run python manage.py collectstatic. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ for more information.